# Coordinates interpolation for video frame synchronization

Tags: c++, gps, coordinates, interpolation

I'm taking an aerial video with gps coordinates. Here's the problem: the video is x frame at second, and the gps module gives me coordinates every second. So I've the coordinate of the first frame for each second. There's a way to interpolate gps coordinates so I will have a gps coordinate for each video frame? Thanks!

ps: I'm doing this in c++

Comment: You will have to interpolate. Which is dead easy if the flight is in a straight line, not so easy if there is a curvature [in x/y or x/z or y/z dimension] or zig-zag []in any dimension] of the flight. One can of course assume that over 1 second the flight is linear, or try to interpolate over a longer timeframe such that you can determine the flight-path - but your curve data for an 360 degree circle in 8 seconds will look like a "stop-sign".

Comment: Do you want to add the coordinates live or can it be computed via post-processing? In the first-case you can use linear interpolation, otherwise i would suggest splines or similar

Comment: Hi guys!  I'm assuming that a short period is linear so I can use linear interpolation (but how?). For it must be in real time!

Comment: Well I know the linear interpolation formula (it's enough search it on google) but how can I map a video frame to the new-calculated coordinate?